# Undefined control sequence item & math inline

Tags: math-mode, itemize

I want to put math inline segment in an item element, but it keeps saying that I've an undefined control sequence error.

I'm trying this way

```latex
\documentclass[UTF8]{article}
\usepackage[UTF8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{enumerate}
\usepackage{amsmath}

\title{My title}
\author{Me}
\date{\today}

\begin{document}
    \maketitle
    \clearpage
    \begin{itemize}
        \item Text $\Ohm$
        \item More text $\mu$F
        \item Lorem ipsum $\mu$F
    \end{itemize}
\end{document}
```

And I also tried this other way.

```latex
\begin{itemize}
    \item Text \(\Ohm\)
    \item More text \(\mu\)F
    \item Lorem ipsum \(\mu\)F
\end{itemize}
```

The error I got is like this:

```
! Undefined control sequence.
<recently read> \Ohm
\item Text $\Ohm$

?
```

How can I make this work ?

Comment: Use `siunitx` package and its syntax for writing of units: `\si{\ohm}`, `\si{\micro\farad}` etc. Read package documentation: *siunitx — A comprehensive (SI) units package*. For complete answer you need to extend your code fragments to MWE (Minimal Working Example), a complete small document which reproduce your problem.

Comment: @Zarko siunitx v3 changed a lot of things, for example is `\si`  deprecated

Comment: @daleif, I do not know yet, I still have version "v2.8e, last revised 2021-04-17." Now check for updates of my MiKTeX installation: now have recent package version "v3.0.2, last revised 2021-05-19." I will ned some time to read it ...

Comment: @daleif, thank you for info. To be honest, changing vide spread uses of commands  names as is `\SI` etc .... I don't like. For example, when new `siunitx` will be available in Overleaf? Fortunately old names still work :-). Improvement for tables is interesting and seems to promising.

Comment: If you have new version of `siunitx` package, i.e. v3.0.2, last revised 2021-05-19, than you can use new package syntax, for example `\unit{\micro\farad}`.

Comment: @Zarko Well availability on overleaf is not really the developers problem. I do understand the move to other names that makes a bit more sense. What I don't like is removal of supported units. There ought to be a way to get these back. Well one an load a previous version, but...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Compilation of my comments:

[image]

As I already mentioned in my comments, for writing od units ar variable with units is recommended to use `siunitx` package. Few days ago is available its new version v3.0.2, last revised 2021-05-19, which introduce many novelties (with all I'm still not familiar) so reading its documentation is strongly recommended (also to me).

```
\documentclass[UTF8]{article}
\usepackage{enumerate}% I prefer enumitem ;-)
\usepackage{siunitx}

\begin{document}
\noindent%
Old syntax (used in \verb+siunitx+, version v2.8e, last revised 2021-04-17 or older):
    \begin{itemize}
        \item Text \si{\ohm}
        \item More text \si{\micro\farad}
        \item Lorem ipsum \si{\micro\farad}
    \end{itemize}
New syntax (needed \verb+siunitx+, version v3.0.2, last revised 2021-05-19):
    \begin{itemize}
        \item Text \unit{\ohm}
        \item More text \unit{\micro\farad}
        \item Lorem ipsum \unit{\micro\farad}
    \end{itemize}
\end{document}
```